# Extending the runtime of a export .avi file

Tags: manipulate, export, code-request, video, size

I've the following code:

```
pe = Flatten@
   Table[Manipulate[
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, end}, ImageSize -> {1980, 1080}], {{end, z}, 
      Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1, Appearance -> "open"}, 
     ContentSize -> 2000], {z, Pi, 2 Pi}];
Export["pe1.avi", pe]
```

Now, the generated .avi file is going way to fast (it completes it within a second).

> Question: How can I improve my code so that I can set the runtime of the .avi file?

Comment: Have you seen ref/format/AVI I told you to look at? One way to go about that is to use FrameRate.

Comment: @Kuba I do not find how to embed that into my code :(